# Balsamiq sketch skin in Sketch App

Tags: sketch-app, mockup, sketching, wireframing

I search to have a Balsamiq mockup skin style in the Sketch mac app.

Is there a library or something else ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I would love to be able to use the UI kit as "rough" as Balsamiq's. Let me know if you found anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a "UI kit" a week ago that had several Balsamiq'y looking elements.

If I find it, I'll post; but here are several that are much-more-refined than Balsamiq. (Balsamiq is much faster IMO; **there's no temptation to enhance the fidelity**)

***"Wireframe Kits"*** https://ui8.net/categories/wireframe-kits